# How to write if condition based on upper query sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to check record using if statement in sql here is my query

```
declare @reporttitle nvarchar(100)

select   
    rs.risk_assesment_id, rs.grade, rs.assessmentdate,
    pat.name, pat.card_id_no, pat.dob, pat.age, pat.mrn,  
    pat.nationality, pat.mobileno,
    @reporttitle as title
from 
    riskassessment_detail rs 
where 
    rs.risk_assesment_id = 22 

IF ((SELECT r.grade 
     FROM riskassessment_detail r 
     WHERE r.risk_assesment_id = 22) ='A') 
   SET @reporttitle = 'AT RISK (15-18)* (A)';
```

`reporttitle` ends up being `null`; I want to get the text how to solve my problem

Comment: What is the else statement for this?  I would set it more like:select   
    @reporttitle = case when rs.grade = 'A' THEN 'AT RISK (15-18)* (A)' ELSE '' END
from 
    riskassessment_detail rs 
where 
    rs.risk_assesment_id = 22

Comment: You don't want IF, you want CASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If am not wrong you need to move the `IF` condition above the `SELECT` query to set the variable with `'AT RISK (15-18)* (A)'` string when `IF` condition is satisfied and show it in `SELECT`

```
declare @reporttitle nvarchar(100)

IF EXISTS (SELECT  1
     FROM riskassessment_detail r 
     WHERE r.risk_assesment_id = 22
       AND r.grade='A') 
   SET @reporttitle = 'AT RISK (15-18)* (A)';


select   
    rs.risk_assesment_id, rs.grade, rs.assessmentdate,
    pat.name, pat.card_id_no, pat.dob, pat.age, pat.mrn,  
    pat.nationality, pat.mobileno,
    @reporttitle as title
from 
    riskassessment_detail rs 
where 
    rs.risk_assesment_id = 22
```